# Riccati Equation y'(t) = ay(t)^2+by(t)+c

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving $y'(t) = -ay^2 + by + c$

I have been attempting to solve the simplified equation:
$\frac{dy}{ay^2+by+c} = dt$

I complete the square so I can integrate it into a $tan^{-1}$ function.  Within the $tan^{-1}$ solution, I have $(x\sqrt{a} + \frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}})$ which would mean the constant ***a*** would always need to be positive.  This does not seem to make sense to me (since ***a*** should be able to be both positive and negative) and my question is whether or not I am going in the right direction in solving this differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -ay^2 + by + c$$

You wrote  $\frac{dy}{ay^2+by+c} = dt$ which is not correct. This should be :
$$\frac{dy}{-ay^2+by+c} = dt$$
If you have trouble with the coefficient $-a$ which can be positive or negative, better write the equation on the form :
$$\frac{dy}{y^2-\frac{b}{a}y-\frac{c}{a}} = -a\,dt$$
Then there is no longer a problem of sign.